# Exiting 'do while ReadLine' loop not working

Tags: c#, console.readline

I am trying to learn C# as I have little experience there. I wanted to set up a Console.Readline in a `Do While` loop so I can read in an unknown amount of values into an array. It never exits so the comparison in the `while` is not working. What is wrong?

```
do
{
    line = Console.Read();
    if (line != null)
        numbers[c++] = line;
    numbers = new int[c+1];

} while (line != null);
```

Comment: You state that you use `Console.ReadLine`, but your code example uses `Console.Read`. Which is it?

Comment: `Console.Read` returns an `int`, so it will never equal `null`.

Comment: Why are you assigning a new array to `numbers`? That will clear out any existing values.

Comment: Try reading the documentation: [Console.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If you *are* using `Console.ReadLine`, the only way it would return null is if you press Ctrl + Z, have you done that, or are you just pressing enter (because that will yield an empty string, not null).

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to store in that array?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at the end? May be your approach is wrong at all?

Comment: @Patrick Sorry I started with ReadLine but that only returns a string so I changed it to Read.  I got confused as I tried lots of things.

Comment: @crashmstr   the documentation I was reading did not mention that would clear the array.  That explains another issue I am seeing.

Comment: @Steve   I am trying to set up an array of unknown size of signed ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would use a `List<int>` to save the input values. This avoids the necessity to redimension the array, and you could use the list as a normal array.

Second, there is a lot of difference between the Console.Read and Console.ReadLine. The first returns one by one the character codes of the characters typed and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will simply return the character code (13) of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. To exit the loop you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> that returns -1, not null.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
int line;
do
{
    line = Console.Read();
    if (line != -1)
        numbers.Add(line);
} while (line != -1);
for(int x = 0; x < numbers.Count(); x++)
   Console.WriteLine(numbers[x]);
```

However, this is probably not what you really want. If you need to store the numbers typed as real integer numbers you need code like this:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
string line = Console.ReadLine();
int number;
do
{
    if(int.TryParse(line, out number))
        numbers.Add(number);

} while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line = Console.ReadLine()));
for(int x = 0; x < numbers.Count(); x++)
   Console.WriteLine(numbers[x]);
```

In this version I get the line input before entering the loop and then continue until the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. In every loop I try to convert the input to a valid integer number.

Note also the usage of TryParse to convert the string to an integer. If your user types something like "abcdef" the TryParse will return false without throwing an exception.

(Thanks [@Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116249/patrick) for its suggestion.)

Comment: If you assign `string line = Console.ReadLine();` and then move `line = Console.ReadLine()` to the end of the do-while you don't need the extra if statement.

Comment: Well I was thinking to switch to a while((line = Console.ReadLine()) != string.Empty) but probably your idea is better

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `Console.Readline()` then `line` will be `null` if you press `Ctrl+Z` (as mentioned by [@Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116249/patrick)). You should check for empty string instead:

```
    do
    {
        line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (line != null)
            numbers[c++] = int.Parse(line); //assigning string to the last element in the array of ints?
            //if you need to parse string to int, use int.Parse() or Convert.ToInt32() 
            //whatever suits your needs
        numbers = new int[c+1];

    } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line));
```

Anyway, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with this code as you're creating new array on every iteration. Moreover, this will not work as you have an array of `int` but assign a `string` value to it.

Comment: It can be null if you press Ctrl + Z

Comment: @Patrick yep, I've updated the answer. Anyway it's not clear what OP does as this will not work either

Comment: You will have difficult times to add a string to an integer array

Comment: @Steve yep, I've mentioned that

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin that doesn't compile at all.